# BGL requires a model that it does not provide itself?

Tags: boost

I'd like to use the parallel MST algorithm [dense_boruvka_minimum_spanning_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/dehne_gotz_min_spanning_tree.html#dense-boruvka-minimum-spanning-tree) from boost.

One required parameter for the interface of that algorithm is a graph which "must be a model of **Vertex List Graph** and **Distributed Edge List Graph**". I found that [the only model](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/DistributedEdgeListGraph.html#models) of boost that incorporates the **Distributed Edge List Graph** concept is the [Distributed Adjacency List](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_adjacency_list.html). However in the section ["Graph Concepts"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_adjacency_list.html) of that model it is explicitly said that

> "[...] the distributed adjacency list **does not model the Vertex List Graph** or Edge List Graph concepts [...]

(Emphasized by me)

At this point I am confused. I'm supposed to pass a data structure to the interface of a boost algorithm which is not provided by the framework? Did I misunderstand something?

NB: I'm pretty new in the boost world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost graph provides generic algorithms around concepts, and has historically included very few models of graph concepts. People will generally have their graphs already in some existing datastructure that they can adapt.

In this light

> At this point I am confused. I'm supposed to pass a data structure to the interface of a boost algorithm which is not provided by the framework?

is not even so strange.

---

The concept of [DistributedAdjacencyList](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_adjacency_list.html) only provides [DistributedVertexListGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/DistributedVertexListGraph.html) when you need [VertexListGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html).

The key difference is highlighted under [DVLG](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/DistributedVertexListGraph.html):

> *A Distributed Vertex List Graph is a graph whose vertices are distributed across multiple processes or address spaces. The `vertices` and `num_vertices` functions retain the same signatures as in the Vertex List Graph concept, but return only the local set (and size of the local set) of vertices.*

In other words: a DVLG is really just a VLG already, just distributed.

What you will want to do is "undistribute" the DVLG using the [VertexListAdaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/vertex_list_adaptor.html):

> *The vertex list graph adaptor adapts any model of Distributed Vertex List Graph in a Vertex List Graph. In the former type of graph, the set of vertices is distributed across the process group, so no process has access to all vertices. In the latter type of graph, however, every process has access to every vertex in the graph. **This is required by some distributed algorithms, such as the implementations of Minimum spanning tree algorithms**.*

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be the "VertexListAdaptor": http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/vertex_list_adaptor.html